# Get ckeditor to leave HTML5 'video' tag 'data-setup' attribute untouched

Tags: regex, ckeditor

CKEditor 4.3.5 (used in ExpressionEngine via Wygwam plugin)

I need to allow a client to add this kind of content to a ckeditor field :

```
<video id="video1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" width="495" height="346" data-setup='{"controls" : true, "autoplay" : false, "preload" : "auto"}'>
    <source src="video.flv" type="video/x-flv">
</video>
```

But after saving the first time the above code gets changed to this :

```
<video class="video-js vjs-default-skin" data-setup="{&quot;controls&quot; : true, &quot;autoplay&quot; : false, &quot;preload&quot; : &quot;auto&quot;}" height="346" id="video1" width="495">
    <source src="video.flv" type="video/x-flv" />
</video>
```

And after saving the the second time it gets changed to this:

```
<video :="" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" data-setup="{" height="346" id="video1" width="495"><source src="video.flv" type="video/x-flv" /></video>
```

Which stops video.js working!

One solution that has been suggested is to use 'protectedSource', but I can't get this to work.

I've added this to config.js:

```
CKEDITOR.config.protectedSource.push( /<video[\s|\S]+?<\/video>/g );
```

Is protectedSource going to work for this?

[Edit: sorry pasted wrong entry - 'extraAllowedContent', should have been 'protectedSource' as now shown]

What is the correct regex that I should add as the value for protectedSource?

Comment: What needs to be transformed precisely?

Comment: sorry I'm not sure what you mean, nothing needs to be transformed, ckeditor is changing the quotes around the 'data-setup' attribute to entities, I want to stop this happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be that ckeditor is behaving correctly when it transforms the inner quotes to entities, and it may be that Wygwam has a bug that causes the 'extra' transformation (when it is saved for a second time) that is breaking the code (however neither of those points provide an answer to my question).

I have found the solution; instead of adding the 'protectedSource' code to the function 'CKEDITOR.editorConfig' in config.js as I was advised to do(!), I added it outside the function, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

CKEditor transforms:

```
data-setup='{"controls" : true, "autoplay" : false, "preload" : "auto"}'>
```

to:

```
data-setup="{&quot;controls&quot; : true, &quot;autoplay&quot; : false, &quot;preload&quot; : &quot;auto&quot;}"
```

And there's nothing wrong with that. It's still the same attribute with the same value, so I don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: it stops video.js working! Edit the entry a second time and the code gets messed up even further.

Comment: That's not true. At least not for a normal CKEditor setup. I loaded the not encoded data, switched to WYSIWYG mode and back to source mode. The attribute was encoded as expected. I switched again and now it wasn't change. Also, reading the attribute works - `CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.editable().findOne( 'video' ).data( 'setup' ) -> 
"{"controls" : true, "autoplay" : false, "preload" : "auto"}"`.

Comment: what can I say, it is true for my setup

Comment: You could for example say how to reproduce your setup ;). Maybe your setup is wrong?

Comment: It's being used in ExpressionEngine via the Wygwam plugin, 'Restrict allowed HTML?' is set to 'no', everything else is the default setting.

Comment: So I guess you need to report a bug to the ExpressionEngine team.

Comment: Thank you, I have sent some info to the Wygwam developers, however even if this is a bug, the information I have requested in my question would still provide a solution, can you help with that please?